# insert apostrophe in sql text table?

Tags: php, sql

I have an sql insert script that updates the sql table in the database when a user types text in a text area, but if a user uses an apostrophe in their text this will not insert the information into the table. this is because sql reads the apostrophe as a closing statement or whatever. but is there a way to use a statement that will allow users to put apostrophes in, i.e. tell sql to use '%s%' or whatever to represent an apostrophe?

Heres the sql update code I'm using:

```
   <?php 

session_start();

include '_config/connection.php'; 

$status = $_POST['status'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM ptb_profiles WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");





if(!$result) 
{ 
echo "The username you entered does not exist"; 
} 
else 
if($status!= mysql_result($result, 0)) 
{ 
echo ""; 


    $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_profiles SET status ='$status' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id'].""); 
}
    if($sql) 
    { 


}
header('Location: http://localhost/ptb1/profile.php?id=' . $_SESSION['user_id'] );
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just escape the apostrophe? It's standard practice to use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) when shoving data into `mysql_query()`s.

Answer (score 0):

Smaller changes and rewrite a line of code -

```
$sql=mysql_query('UPDATE ptb_profiles SET status ="'. mysql_real_escape_string($status) .'" WHERE id='.$_SESSION['user_id']);
```

Comment: `addslashes` _must not_ be used to escape SQL input. It does not serve this purpose.

Comment: This is not a good answer addslashes does not properly vet the status variable. The other answer of using mysql_real_escape_string() is correct.

Comment: I have also described `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: You still left the bad advice in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_profiles SET status ='$status' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");`

to this:

`$sql=mysql_query('UPDATE ptb_profiles SET status ="'. mysql_real_escape_string($status) .'" WHERE id='.$_SESSION['user_id']);`

P.S. Never insert variables directly from $_POST or $_GET or $_REQUEST directly into your SQL or you'll end up with a SQL Injection vulnerability.